# How to get a daily mean

Tags: r, rstudio

I got the following question. Currently I am working with RStudio and i want to get a daily mean, however I just started to learn Rstudio and don't know how to continue...

my data set looks like this:

1. row (day): 2019-12-01; 2019-12-01; 2019-12-02; 2019-12-02; 2019-12-02; 2019-12-03;.....
2. row (value): 1; 2; 3; 1; 3; 3; 1;...

And i want my dataset to look like this:

1. row (day): 2019-12-01; 2019-12-02; 2019-12-03;.....
2. row (average_value): 1; 2; 3;....

Which Code do I need to get it like that? Can someone help me?
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Look into `dplyr` package. You can achieve this using `group_by()` and `summarise()`

Comment: Try `aggregate(value ~ day, yourDataset, mean)`

Comment: @GKi, please post your comment as an answer ...

Answer (score 1):

you can also use library dplyr

```html
library(dplyr)
value<-c(3,7,3,4,5)
DF<-data.frame(Day=c("2019-12-01","2019-12-01","2019-12-02","2019-12-02","2019-12-02"),value=value)

Day value
1 2019-12-01     3
2 2019-12-01     7
3 2019-12-02     3
4 2019-12-02     4
5 2019-12-02     5

DF %>% group_by(Day) %>% summarize(average = mean(value)) 

Day        average
  <fct>        <dbl>
1 2019-12-01       5
2 2019-12-02       4
```

`dplyr` makes this very easy through the use of the `group_by()` function, which splits the data into groups. When the data is grouped in this way `summarize()` can be used to collapse each group into a single-row summary. summarize() does this by applying an aggregating or summary function to each group, built-in functions are `mean, median, min, and max`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` and `mean` to get daily mean like:

```
aggregate(value ~ day, yourDataset, mean)
#         day    value
#1 2019-12-01 1.500000
#2 2019-12-02 2.333333
#3 2019-12-03 2.000000
```

Data:

```
yourDataset <- structure(list(day = structure(c(18231, 18231, 18232, 18232, 
18232, 18233, 18233), class = "Date"), value = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 
3, 3, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```